# Have Captain America and Wolverine ever fought?

Tags: marvel, wolverine, captain-america

Both have advanced healing powers, one has an Adamantium coated skeleton and claws and the other has a Vibranium shield. Wolverine has his special sense ability, but Captain America has brilliant techniques.

Have they ever fought, and if so who won?

Comment: As with [the other question you recently raised](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/100415/have-spider-man-and-flash-ever-fought), please phrase these questions as "Have character A and character B ever fought?" so that they are answerable.

Comment: OK and thanks sir for your advice

Comment: Much much better. I look forward to seeing the answer

Answer (score 33, accepted):

**All the time.** Seriously. Cap and Wolverine are both heroes, but have *wildly* different worldviews.

Unfortunately, they've fought *so often*, and usually with such a narrow margin if "who won", that it's really impossible to call either one a clearly superior fighter.

[This blog](http://hero-envy.blogspot.com/2013/02/captain-america-vs-wolverine.html) goes over some stats and historical battles between the two. They note that of the twelve matchups that they selected to focus on, Cap came out on top 5:1, but acknowledges the fact that often times, the win was very fuzzy.

- CAPTAIN AMERICA ANNUAL #8: Draw
- THE X-MEN VS THE AVENGERS #1: None
- THE X-MEN VS THE AVENGERS #4: None
- INFINITY WAR #2: None
- CAPTAIN AMERICA #404: Wolverine
- CAPTAIN AMERICA #405: Captain America
- WOLVERINE: ORIGINS #4: Captain America (Edge)
- WOLVERINE: ORIGINS #4: Wolverine (Edge)
- WOLVERINE: ORIGINS #5: Captain America
- WOLVERINE: ORIGINS #20: Captain America
- AVENGERS VS X-MEN #3: Captain America

The problem is that largely speaking, they're pretty well matched, so it really comes down to a matter of circumstances and the specific writer of the story. For example, in Avengers vs X-Men, Wolverine was doing pretty well against Cap before the rest of the Avengers intervened to end the fight prematurely.

Answer (score -5):

Captain America would lose due to the fact that Logan’s claws can cut through the shield due to it being wakanda vibranium and not Antarctica vibranium which is anti metal he can dodge but he can still die wolverine has actually killed Steve after slicing the shield in half and then stabbed him through the chest

Comment: Up until "he can still die", that sounds a bit speculative (or if founded, you should provide evidence). After that, about Wolverine killing Cap - when was that? Which issue?